# Set another condition in THEN section in case statement sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a situation where I need to set

```
CASE JDT1.TransType 
   WHEN 46 THEN  JDT1.Debit > 0
END
```

which leads to error , how can I overcome this issue , my full query is

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Supplier_Enquiry]   
AS
BEGIN

SELECT        OCRD.CardCode, OCRD.CardName, OCRD.GroupCode, OCRG.GroupName, OCRD.CreditLine, ISNULL(JDT1.FCCurrency,'LKR') AS Currency, JDT1.RefDate, 
                         CAST(OJDT.BaseRef AS int) AS 'Document Number',
CASE  WHEN JDT1.TransType=18 THEN 'Invoice'
          WHEN JDT1.TransType=19 THEN 'Credit Memo'
          WHEN JDT1.TransType=204 THEN 'A/P Down Payment'
          WHEN JDT1.TransType=46 THEN 'Vendor Payment'
          WHEN JDT1.TransType=30 THEN 'Journal Entry'

          END AS 'Transaction', 
                         JDT1.DueDate, JDT1.Debit - JDT1.Credit AS 'Outstanding', JDT1.Debit AS [Amount Dr], JDT1.Credit AS [Amount Cr],ISNULL(VPM1.CheckNum, 0) AS CheckNum
FROM            VPM1 INNER JOIN
                         OVPM ON VPM1.DocNum = OVPM.DocEntry RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         JDT1 INNER JOIN
                         OCRD ON JDT1.ShortName = OCRD.CardCode INNER JOIN
                         OCRG ON OCRD.GroupCode = OCRG.GroupCode INNER JOIN
                         OJDT ON JDT1.TransId = OJDT.TransId ON OVPM.TransId = OJDT.TransId
WHERE        (OCRD.CardType = 'S')  
AND
(

CASE JDT1.TransType 
    WHEN 46 THEN  JDT1.Debit > 0

END

) 
END
```

need some guide on to correct the issue

Comment: what error you are getting please specify.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with this: 

    CASE JDT1.TransType 
       WHEN 46 THEN  JDT1.Debit > 0
    END

Comment: I want to apply JDT1.Debit > 0 only for JDT1.TransType -->46

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression*. It computes a scalar *value*. It's not a *control flow* primitive and SQL Server doesn't have boolean values.

Comment: You're question has been answered, but for future reference: If you get an error, the absolute *least* you can do is post the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this checks the Debit >0 only if TransType = 46

```
...
AND (JDT1.TransType <>46 OR (JDT1.TransType = 46 and JDT1.Debit > 0))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need case in this situation at all:

```
WHERE OCRD.CardType = 'S' 
AND 
(
    JDT1.TransType <> 46
    OR JDT1.Debit > 0
)
```

Comment: this is not checking JDT1.Debit > 0 only for JDT1.TransType -->46

Comment: @Mark yes, you are correct, but it gets the same result as if you did. If TransType is not 46, we don't care that the Debit is 0 or lower.